# What can cause this event to stop being invoked?

Tags: c#, events, .net-4.5, eventhandler

#### The Problem:

I am using asynchronous event handling in a class that invokes an event about 60 times per second. If I run the software for several hours I find that it eventually gets to a state where the event stops invoking the assigned delegate without seeing any exceptions or user input.

Here is the distilled version of the event code I am using:

```csharp
class DataSource
{
    public event EventHandler<DataReadyEventArgs> DataReady;

    private void OnDataReady()
    {
        EventHandler<DataReadyEventArgs> evt = DataReady;
        if (evt != null)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Invoking DataReady...");
            DataReadyEventArgs args = new DataReadyEventArgs();
            evt.BeginInvoke(this, args, new AsyncCallback(DataReadyHandled), null);
        }
    }

    private void DataReadyHandled(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        AsyncResult aresult = result as AsyncResult;
        EventHandler<DataReadyEventArgs> evt = aresult.AsyncDelegate as EventHandler<DataReadyEventArgs>;
        if (evt != null)
        {
            try
            {
                evt.EndInvoke(result);
                Trace.WriteLine("DataReady was handled.");
            }
            catch
            { }
        }
    }
}

class DataConsumer
{
    public DataConsumer(DataSource src)
    {
        src.DataReady += HandleDataReady;
    }

    public void HandleDataReady(object sender, DataReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Handling DataReady");
    }
}
```

To avoid writing out further code to give the full picture, you can also make the following assumptions:

- There is always a strong reference to the `DataSource` instance so it is not being garbage collected while the `DataConsumer` is expecting an event
- The `DataConsumer` attaches its handler method once and does not remove it until the instance is garbage collected.

Here is the weird part; When I attach a debugger to the software in its broken state, I can see that the `evt` variable in `OnDataReady()` references an `EventHandler` instance and is not null. It actually calls BeginInvoke but the `HandleDataReady` method is never entered. The debugger shows that the `EventHandler` base class's Method property is null though. I can't seem to figure out how it is possible that the `EventHandler` is being changed.

#### The (First) Question:

What can cause the event in the above code to stop being invoked after several hours of runtime?

#### My Best Guess:

Could something completely unrelated in my application be corrupting the memory for the `EventHandler`? I am using both native and managed c++ libraries.

---

#### Update:

My best guess turns out to be unlikely, as I have run some other tests that make me reasonably sure the native libraries are not leaking or corrupting memory.

After reproducing the problem another time with logging, I can see that the event is not stopping entirely but being invoked on a ~19 hour interval! Obviously there is a long-running operation or blocking somewhere in the handler delegate.

To be certain that it's my code and not .NET, I have an updated question...

#### The (Second) Question:

Is there any behaviour built in to .NET (4.5) or its garbage collector that can block invocation of an EventHandler?

Comment: have you used any memory mapping tools to get a further look inside your RAM after those couple of hours of work? [This](https://github.com/Microsoft/perfview) is a good tool, also in combination you could leave VS in debug mode and then look at the diagnostic tool.

Comment: The tests are being run on another system without VS so I am forced to use remote debugging. I will try PerfView on the next overnight test though.

Comment: I'm surprised that works at all; surely `EventHandler evt = aresult.AsyncDelegate as EventHandler;` needs to be `EventHandler<DataReadyEventArgs> evt = aresult.AsyncDelegate as EventHandler<DataReadyEventArgs>;` ?

Comment: as a random "try something simpler to see if it works", I wonder if the async callback handling is making it angry; it might be easier to try: `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => evt(this, args));` (or `_ => { ... evt(this, args); ...}` if you want to add post-processing etc. I also wonder if the empty `catch { }` might be hiding problems that `EndInvoke` is trying to tell you about - you could also try your existing code, but `catch (Exception ex) { Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message); }`

Comment: @Marc, I admit that I didn't just copy and paste this code so the error your pointed out is not present in the original code. The actual code is quite a bit more complex and I do not have permission to post it in full. The catch block does handle the exception appropriately but there is no exception being thrown in the async callback anyways.